# Reuse CSR for multiple certificates for multiple variants of the same app

Tags: ios

We are developing an app that will be used by mobile operators and each will have their own version, for example there could be a T-Mobile version, an AT&T version and so on.

The app is the same in each case except things like the name and logos will be changed.

I have a workspace which contains a library which contains all the code, and then have created different projects within the workspace where the app can be renamed and have different icons and images etc. The library is unsigned, each project will sign with its own set of profiles.

I am planning on using an app id naming scheme such as com.OurCompanyName.NameOfApp.OperatorA, com.OurCompanyName.NameOfApp.OperatorB etc.

My question is are there any gotchas I should be aware of in terms of certificates, CSRs, profiles and build machines etc. 
For example 
 - the apps use APN and therefore each needs its own push certificates using its own set of app ids. Can I use the same CSR with each push certificate or should a different CSR be created for each push certificate?
 - are there going to be problems building all of apps on the same build machine, or will XCode and the keychain get confused if there are multiple sets of provisioning profiles and certificates etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reuse the same CSR for different apps. I use the same CSR for all of my half-a-dozen apps in the App Store, and I don't see any reason that using APN would change that.